# Syncing two videos in opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I was working on a project which involves synchronization of two videos.
For example, let's say I have two videos which display timestamps,
in the first video timestamp is 11:59:03, in the second video timestamp is 11:59:17, so the difference will be 14 seconds. Now I have to somehow make the shorter video(11:59:03) jump to 11:59:17 and run from this point simultaneously, therefore the two videos will be synchronized.
What i have tried so far:

```
frameDelay = 14 #FPS of video
delay = 0
frameNum = 0
x = 0

shortCap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameDelay*difference) #skipping that much frames
longCap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

while True:

    ret1, frame1 = shortCap.read() #running fast, cam3
    ret2, frame2 = longCap.read()

    frame1 = cv2.resize(frame1, (600, 600))
    frame2 = cv2.resize(frame2, (600, 600))
    
    cv2.imshow('cam3', frame1)
    cv2.imshow('cam1', frame2)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)&0xff

    if key == 27:
        break

shortCap.release()
longCap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I was able to skip the initial difference frames but after that, as the time increases, the shorter video was running fast (overtaking the second video).

Comment: What do you mean by running fast? Is there an FPS difference between the videos?

Comment: @Meto by running fast i meant, the shortCap is ahead of longCap, only the initial time was same, after that shortcap somehow moves ahead of longcap thus destroying the purpose of synchronization.
shortcap fps is = 14.08
longcap fps = 15.15

Comment: If a jump between frames after synchronization is not occurring then I believe the issue is the FPS difference of the sources. On a real time system I don't have a solution. Maybe you can adjust stream frame rate while delaying 14 FPS video by 1 frame. If its not real time then you can re-record the videos with same frame rate. But remember all of my arguments are false if there is a jump occurring in video stream.

Comment: @Meto okay, how do i delay 14 fps video by 1 frame?

Comment: `cv2.waitKey(n)` => here "n" is actually the delay before each frame and as i remember it can take double values. So if you can adjust the correct amount of delay then you should be fine. But in your code you are streaming both videos in the same loop so when you adjust `cv2.waitKey()` there, it will effect both videos. Maybe you can use threads or separate processes.

Comment: @Meto so how do you propose to stream 2 videos simultaneously? for correct synchronization?
Also, delay should be calculated like this : 1/(15.15-14.08) right?

Answer (score 0):

> waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it
> is suitable for image display). waitKey(25) will display a frame for
> 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed.

so you have to calculate the difference in ms.

```
(fps1-fps2)*ms_for_each_frame
```

My proposal would be re capturing contents in same FPS. If that's not possible then you can use a 3rd party application to alter FPS rates such as FFMPEG. Lastly you can start video playbacks on separate synchronized threads with adjusted `waitkey(n)` values but that would involve also thread synchronization and more complexity. Pick your poison :D.